# TypeError: tasks.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working with my friends on some application, where he is sending me through rest API tasks. I have an error: TypeError: tasks.map is not a function. Please help :)

````
const [tasks, changeTasks] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
 api
   .get(endpoints.tasks)
   .then(({ data }) => {
     console.log(data);
     changeTasks(data.tasks);
     console.log(tasks);
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
   });
}, []);

return (
 <UserTemplate>
   <StyledHeading big>Twoje dzisiejsze zadania</StyledHeading>
   <StyledGrid>
     {tasks.map(({ name, description, id }) => (
       <TaskCard name={name} description={description} key={id} />
     ))}
   </StyledGrid>
 </UserTemplate>
);
};```

> From the backend I am receiving this:

``` {
 "tasks": [
     {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "vacuming",
         "data": "2020-01-01",
         "description": "",
         "priority": "0"
     },
 ]
}`
````

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your `tasks` state with `[]`, not with `''`. `.map` doesn't exist on a string, empty or otherwise.

```
const [tasks, changeTasks] = useState('');
```

to

```
// set is a better convention here as it's a setter
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

Now it won't error on your first render and will properly display your tasks after your promise resolves and an ensuing render.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect with an empty array as a dependency array will only run, after the component has mounted. But your render function will run even before that. So, calling .map() on empty string is giving you this error. If you remove the [ ], then it will run always. Assuming that is also something you do not want, you might want to check if tasks is an array or not inside your render method and based on then use .map().